# Android Screen Zoom like iPhone

Tags: android, zooming

I want to make an Android app.What i want in this app is the magnification feature which was included after android 4.1 I want the entire display to zoom like the way it happens in iPhones using more than 2 fingers.If anyone can suggest a few links i would appreciate it.

Comment: I could not find anything to start with as I have never done anything like this before.I have surfed the internet for this but i got only the setting that can be changed from android 4.1 onwards.Nothing for the development of an app

Comment: It would be nice if you could give me ideas to start my app with

Comment: Even a few useful links would be a great help